# Visual studio (2013) intellisense for C# parsed json object

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2013, javascript-intellisense

I have an Asp.Net application, and I am trying to do as much as I can on client site. So, I am passing my C# objects serialized to JSON string to my clients (website with JavaScript) to have all information that I need.

Now on client side, I have no intellisense for the objects,  because they are anonymous.

Is there something built-in, or a lib or extension,  that could make my classes, or eg.  classes that I mark with an attribute, available for intellisense in JavaScript.

1. I mean, I could programmatically convert my C# classes to JSON and save them to a file after each build.  But I don't know how thus then could be used for intellisense.
2. I could also convert the C# classes to JavaScript classes,  so that these are available in JavaScript for intellisense, but I think this is hard to convert because I would have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to share your C# classes with your javascript.

But as it sounds to me, you are looking for typescript. This is a type safe version of javascript created by Microsoft.

This should also give you way better intelisense for the code.

Check it out here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript